# Is there any open source library which can convert sql query language to its corresponding mongodb query?

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb

Have been working on some project where I need to convert SQL query to MongoDB query language. few online converter tools I came across,

- https://www.site24x7.com/tools/sql-to-mongodb.html
- http://www.querymongo.com/

I have a similar requirement.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB provides [BI connector](https://www.mongodb.com/products/bi-connector) which can execute SQL queries against a MongoDB database.

The [mysql example](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/current/connect/mysql/) may be helpful.

I am unaware of a MongoDB-supported translation tool of SQL to MQL.

Comment: Thanks! but the aim here is to generate the corresponding Mongo query through a dirty script(python, java), not the execution in some specific DB provider.